# How to process excel in azure data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have multiple excel files in a blob storage and sheet name in those files are different while loading in the files in azure sql database in azure data flow how the sheet name to be handled.
Note : I have to do it in azure data flow,i tried doing in azure pipeline its working

Comment: it have to be csv, excel (as far as I know) is not a well know type (due formulas / formatting, etc)

Comment: Are you trying to make the sheet name dynamic? You could use an inline dataset for XLSX in the dataflow source and parameterize it. Or you can have a different Source transformation for each sheet inside your Excel workbook.

Comment: Yes the sheet name should be dynamic because I want first sheet of every Excel present in blob and load it database because I want merge data of all the files.incannot use different source transformation for each sheet because I have around 800 files in blob which should get merge together.

Comment: Referencing a sheet by index is not possible today, you must use a sheet name. However, we are evaluating adding this to the Excel connector.

Comment: Hi @SHIBASHISHTRIPATHY, If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data factory supports Excel connector now, but still couldn't support dynamic choose the sheet index for now.

Others have added comment in [Data Factory feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/19807720-add-excel-as-source) but didn't get reply:
[image]

I think you also could post a [new feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory), we could help you vote up it and Data Factory Product Team may see it.

Comment: Ya checked  everywhere excel doesnot support dynamic sheet and I did code in databricks python and ran the pipeline in adf